# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<WebGLRenderingContext> has no method 'getShaderPrecisionFormat'

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm using ThreeJS for an application I'm developing at work, in particular the WebGL renderer. It was working fine about a week and a half ago, but when I came back to work today I'm getting this error when trying to run my application in Chrome:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getShaderPrecisionFormat'

I debugged my application in Chrome and it looks like the WebGLRenderingContext has no method 'getShaderPrecisionFormat'; any suggestions as to what may have happened to lead to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2769) thread and see if it helps you see what happened. It lead to some changes in `webGLRenderer.js`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in r56+. (And possibly in r55, but I don't have a version of it to check)

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L7478

```
        if ( _gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat === undefined ) {

            _gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat = function() { 

                return {
                    "rangeMin"  : 1,
                    "rangeMax"  : 1,
                    "precision" : 1
                };

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you haven't overwritten renderer.context because else you'll have to show some code because I haven't gotten a single clue for now??

Comment: Hello, Here is a fiddle with sample code from the ThreeJS site: http://jsfiddle.net/SDe5m/. This fiddle fails with the error listed above on my work machine (RHEL6) in both Chrome and Firefox. However, if I remove the ThreeJS script inclusion line (which is r54) and instead include the r50 version through the JSFiddle menu, the same sample code works fine on the same machine in both Chrome and Firefox. I see that r54 was released on Dec 25th, perhaps it's just the r54 version that does not work on my machine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest driver for your systems GPU becuase you are missing a quite important part of the webgl spec?? The reason it works in r50 is because we didn't use that function in three.js then. And now we do.